# git branch contains other unwanted branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

The admin has told me not to merge develop into my branches before pushing them to remote, and that I should create new branches based on master, that way no code from develop will accidentally get merged into master. OK, that has worked fine for several weeks, but a couple of days ago I accidentally merged develop into one of my branches. That didn't create a big problem for the admin, he just told me not to do it again, but since then I started using *"git branch --contains"* to make sure.

**Problem**: 
When I fetch the remote master and run "git branch --contains", it shows that develop is part of it:

```
git branch --contains
  develop
* master
```

How can that be possible??

I see 3 possible explanations:

1. remote master was at some point accidentally merged with develop
2. some unknown error
3. I'm not updating my local branch correctly with the fetched master

---

1. is very unlikely since the admin is a guru who couldn't possibly have let that happen
2. is what I suspect is happening
3. possible, but I think I've been doing it correctly all these weeks with this code:

---

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git clean -f
git pull origin master
```

So as long as develop is in master I cannot create/push any new branches.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my understanding of `git branch --contains`. It doesn't list branches contained in the currently checked out branch, but branches which contain **it**.

So to know if `master` contains `develop` I should do

```
git checkout develop
git branch --contains
* develop
```

So there was no problem after all. As this shows, `master` is not part of the list of branches which contain `develop`.

While this showed that `develop` did contain `master`, but that's ok.

```
git checkout master
git branch --contains
  develop
* master
```

Comment: This will be easier to remember if you also remember that `git branch --contains` takes an SHA-1 argument: `git branch --contains bbfec67` tells you which branches have that commit.  Without a final argument, `git branch --contains` means "resolve commit `HEAD` to an SHA-1 ID, and then find branches that contain that."

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your local `develop` branch hasn't been updated since the last time that a commit made it all the way into `master`. Make sure that your local `develop` branch is up to date:

```
git checkout develop
git fetch
git merge --ff-only origin/develop
```

A good way to figure out what's going on with your branch topology is to run this command:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

Or this one, if you're more of a GUI person:

```
gitk --all
```

You'll see a graph showing all of your commits, with colored markers labeling the position of each local and remote-tracking branch. It's a good way to keep track of what's where, when you have lots of branches and complicated workflows.